# Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem and non-principal ultrafilters

Tags: ultrafilters, set-theory

Somewhat related to my other question [Existence of non-principal ultrafilters on sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76495),
is it known whether it is consistent with ZF that every infinite set has a free (non-principal) ultrafilter, but not every filter on a Boolean algebra can be extended to an ultrafilter?  (Again, use you favorite interpretation of "infinite" here.  Large cardinals may be used.)

Comment: In Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice" it is stated that the Prime Ideal Theorem may fail while every infinite set has a non-trivial ultrafilter. The proof is the exercise 8.5 (I don't have time to sketch it right now, hence the comment).